# I need to implement Image Indexing on a color palette using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Given a directory containing images only, I need to index the files using Lucene Indexing (using inverted indexing). Assuming we are provided with a tool to extract color percentage(not specific RGB percentage), how should I use the Lucene library so that when I query for images having green colour, I get the result set as Images having green color percentage in descending order??
How should I modify the Fields files? If I create a new ColorField File what can be its data-type to facilitate minimum changes?
I also need to modify the analyzers files?

Comment: Hi, i know this is not related but i was looking for a tool to extract color percentage, can you recommend what you are using?

Comment: @Omri I built it myself as a demo, its not fully functional. Moreover what kind of tool you want? should it give only rgb values or the concentration of the particular colors(comination of rgb) in the image?

Comment: I'm looking to get the rgb values... i found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042789/getting-a-colour-scheme-from-an-image Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would index the the percentages you want to search by as separate fields.  Using an [IntField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntField.html), [DoubleField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DoubleField.html), [FloatField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FloatField.html), [LongField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongField.html) or similar, would probably make the most sense.

For instance:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StoredField("path",path));
doc.add(new FloatField("green",percentageGreen,Field.Store.NO));
doc.add(new FloatField("red",percentageRed,Field.Store.NO));
//etc.
```

The details, such as which numeric field to use, whether to store the percentages, etc. would depend on your requirements.

You could then search those percentages using a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html), or Sort based on them with the appropriate [IndexSearcher.search call](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29), such as:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("green",SortField.Type.FLOAT));
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query,maxResults,sort);
```

Comment: thanks, this is the alternative approach i am implementing now